# How to find if the particular emailID exists or not dynamically in the DynamoDB?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am using node js in the lambda function. I need to save some of the details in the dynamo db..While passing the values i need to check whether the emailid exists in the dynamo db or not..If the emailid already exists it should return error...Only if the mail id is not present data's should be stored in the db...As of now i will post the code which i did to check whether the emailID exists in the db or not.

```
 const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();


var tableName = "Testing";

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

console.log(event)

let login = {
         TableName: 'Testing',
         Key: {'EmailID': 'abc@gmail.com'}
        };


docClient.get(login, function(err, data){
    if(err){
        console.log("error");
    }else{
        console.log("Succes");
   }

  if (typeof data.Item.EmailID === 'undefined') {
        // variable is undefined
        console.log("useridndefined");
        }
    else {
        console.log("Found and EmailID attribute: "+ data.Item.EmailID);

        }


});
}
```

Am getting error:

```
 {
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: a3b80d66-c6ab-4de2-8bdc-195d1b0eafac Process exited before completing request"
}

{"errorMessage":"The provided key element does not match the schema","errorType":"ValidationException","stackTrace":["Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)","Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)","Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)","Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)","Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)","AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)","/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10","Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)","Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)","Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)"]}
```

Please help me to do that. **Only if the emailID exits in the db it should return success else not present**

My schema:

```
CustomerName String : abc
EmailID      String : abc@gmail.com   
Password     String : abc
Name         String : abc
```

Comment: Are you trying to store `emailID` in dynamoDB only if it is not present ?

Comment: Also, you are getting this error because you are not providing complete primary key to the `docClient`.

Comment: @Atul Kumar yes am trying to store the emailID only if the emildID is not present

Comment: @Atul Kumar How to give complete primary key to doc client

Comment: can you share your schema ?

Comment: @Atul I attached my schema in my question.Thank u

Comment: @samikshap what is the hash key and range key of the table ?

Comment: So the primary key is CustomerName  Sort Key is EmailID ...AM using DynamoDB

Comment: Why don't you try GSI (Global seconday index ) to query?

Comment: How to try that? i just need to check whether the emilID exists or not

Answer (score 0):

Since your primary key is customerName and sortKey is EmailID, you will have to pass both while calling get.

```
let login = {
    TableName: 'Testing',
    Key: {
      'EmailID': 'abc@gmail.com',
      'CustomerName': name
    }
};
```

or you can pass just the primary key and query all the emails for a customerName

Comment: Sir...am getting the output as null....Btw i need to check whether the particular emilIDexists or not

Comment: With the current key schema you will have to check whether a customerName with email exists or not.
I guess the no of items are zero when no records are found. Null might indicate empty response, if you are not getting any errors.

Comment: Sir...I gave the customername and emailId which exists in the db...In logs am getting always success even for the wrong input then and in the output am getting null

Comment: Success indicates the get operation to Dynamo is successful. It does not mean the present or not. For that you will have to check items in response

Comment: I need to check whether the particular emailID exists or not..If exists it should prompt that emailID already exists....Pls help me to do that